# Proper way using timeouts with serial port and ReadAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mono, serial-port, rs485

I have used serial port with its original methods like BytesToRead, Read and Write before. As it is said that these are unreliable and I had a lot busy waiting I am trying to switch to its asynchronous methods.

I need to read from serial port with 2 different time outs. First timeout is between two messages (2000 ms here) and second is between 2 chars (10 ms here). Therefore I change ReadTimeout for each ReadAsync call like this:

```
    public int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, bool isFirstChar)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        try
        {
            m_serialPort.ReadTimeout = isFirstChar ? 2000 : 10;
            Task<int> task = m_serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count);
            task.Wait();
            return task.Result;
        } catch (AggregateException err)
        {
            stopWatch.Stop();
            int cnt = 0;
            foreach (Exception e in err.InnerExceptions)
            {
                if (e is TimeoutException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception {0}: {1} Timeout: {2} ms", ++cnt, e.Message, stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Output when an AggregateException occurs and no bytes are received:

> Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2014 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2014 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2014 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2014 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2014 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 3584 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2014 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2017 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2012 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2011 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2016 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2012 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2011 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2013 ms
>   Exception 1: The operation has timed-out. Timeout: 2013 ms

My questions are now:

- **Is this a proper way using ReadAsync method with .Wait()?**
- **Is it ok to change ReadTimeout everytime before the ReadAsync call?**
- **Should I use CancellationToken as parameter in ReadAsync instead, and if yes whats the best way of doing that?**

Comment: which .NET Version is this? because I cannot find SerialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync() on MSDN and neither gives intellisense this as option ofr me

Comment: I am using 4.5! Have a look here: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I am still confused, `BaseStream` is of type `Stream` and the method `ReadAsynch` belongs to `StreamReader`. I cannot reproduce your code.

Comment: No, this is not proper.  Use exceptions *only* to handle exceptional conditions.  Your output says that it is entirely normal to get a timeout.  And your code does not treat it as exceptional either.  So don't use a timeout at all.

Comment: No, a timeout isnt normal, because it does normally not occur. In my example (output) connection was lost.... I also have to use a timeout to determine whether a message is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:** you use an asynchronous method in a synchronous way.
usually you would give it a callback function an wait until an event is fired and this function can be executed.
Here are examples [1](http://www.dotnetperls.com/async) & [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for asynch await methodology

**Question 2:** If your circumstances require you to do so. I don't see why not.

Unfortunately I yet don't know how to answer your third question so I leave it open for now.